# Can't connect to SQL Server database from Local IIS over HTTPS

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, iis

I'm working on an application using ASP.NET MVC5 and connecting to my SQL Server database with `SqlClient` (Dapper.NET)

I've been using Local IIS without a problem on `http://localhost:port/` but now I have switched over to HTTPS (self-signed key), with a binding of https://www.mysite.com and the hosts file is redirecting that URL to 127.0.0.1

The problem that I am having is the following:

> A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process. (provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The specified data could not be decrypted.\r\n)

This is happening when I am attempting to connect to my SQL Server database with the standard `connection.Open()` call.

I've read around about people suggesting to restart the IIS server, or to reconfigure the SQL Server database to have encryption forced off. I've checked both of these, but that doesn't resolve the problem.

Can anyone shed some light on what might be going wrong here?

Comment: Try adding `Encrypt=True` to your connection String and see if it makes difference.

Comment: @Glk.net Yes I have tried this, but the error changes to `The certificate chain was issued by an authority that is not trusted` so I set `TrustServerCertificate=True` and I'm back to the same error.

Comment: I'm going to untag this as "dapper"; it isn't a dapper issue - until ADO.NET can connect, dapper isn't even involved.

Answer (score 0):

I know why this is...

It's a component available via NuGet called NCrypt which I've just spent 6 hours isolating.

I'm not sure how, but when it's present in my bin folder it interferes somehow with the handshake process between the code and SQL Server.

When it's removed, voila! SQL connects as expected.

Comment: Don't think it was any issue with NuGet packages. Was a while ago but I think it my issue was something to do with project properties. I remember it being something solved by chance.

Comment: It was NCrypt - I started from scratch, removed it entirely with no other changes and now the connection works.
I have no idea how or why, but it might have had something to do with it being the same name as a Windows dll.
Try it yourself :)